# Overlay dynamic text and images on Video android

Tags: android, canvas, android-camera, video-editing

I have captured a video from camera preview.The video contains sound too. Next what I want to do is write some text on video or draw something on it and then save like snapchat does.

I tried searching but couldn't get any solution.
I am clueless on how I will be able to achieve this. Can any one guide for the same?

Comment: use a `FrameLayout` with 2 child views: a video at the bottom and some view drawing text and images on the top

Comment: Thanks @pskink , once I am done with drawing part, How I will be saving the video with text or images drawn ?

Comment: you would need some external library for that, i think

Comment: do you have any idea regarding that ? @pskink

Comment: regarding that external  library?  no, i don't

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFmpeg library
.You can directly use

`ffmpeg -i input.avi -i logo.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10' output.avi`

for further information you can see this link
[ffmepg github link](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)